# Crystal Report Database Login Parameter

Tags: c#, database-connection, crystal-reports-xi

Hi i have a windows base c# application developed Using Crystal report as my reporting tools. i already supplied all the login and database info but when i ran and deploy it.. it still ask for the database logon.

here is my code below.

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();


        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        rpt.Load("C:/Operation/Reports/po.rpt");

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "192.4.4.4";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Operations";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "xxxxxx";




        ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
        ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
        ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = DbClass.PONumber;
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["ParameterPO"];
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

        crParameterValues.Clear();
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);



        CrTables = rpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crpt.Refresh();
        crpt.ReportSource = rpt;
```

My Head is aching where the problem is... if someone know's about this please give me an idea..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open your connection first. Using this:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("xxx");
 myConnection.Open();
 // Your Code
 myConnection.Close();
```

And then close the connection.

Comment: i guess this is not necessary coz im not using SQL here...no sql connection involved as i already set the fields in crystal report...all i need is the logon information to view the report.